# FCM notification is not receiving in backgroun but in received in foreground. Any suggestion for background(when app killed)?

Tags: android, firebase-cloud-messaging, android-8.0-oreo

I have created channel with high pirority for oreo. I am receiving notification in foreground from firebase console at oreo but not in background(when app is killed from RAM).
Below oreo everything works fine...

```
//fcm onMessage


 @Override
public void onMessageReceived(@NonNull RemoteMessage remoteMessage) {
    Intent intent=new Intent(this,HomeActivity.class);
    intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
    PendingIntent pendingIntent=PendingIntent.getActivity(this,0,intent,PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);
    final String title=remoteMessage.getData().get("title");
    final String msg=remoteMessage.getData().get("body");
    if( title!=null && msg!=null){
        final Notification not = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this, CHANNEL_WELCOME)
                .setContentTitle(title)
                .setContentText(msg)
                .setPriority(NotificationCompat.PRIORITY_HIGH)
                .setCategory(NotificationCompat.CATEGORY_ALARM)
                .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_logo_final)
                .setContentIntent(pendingIntent)
                .build();
        NotificationManagerCompat compat = NotificationManagerCompat.from(getApplicationContext());
        compat.notify(33333, not);
    }

}
```

Comment: first check you mobile isnt in battery saving mode sir. and then check the permission of your android background services of your aap is notification is on or not.

Comment: both checked and green to go.

Answer (score 0):

There are tow type of notification
1-Notification messages, sometimes thought of as "display messages." These are handled by the FCM SDK automatically.
2-Data messages, which are handled by the client app
you need to handle both 
@Override
    public void onMessageReceived(RemoteMessage remoteMessage) {

```
    Log.d(TAG, "FROM:" + remoteMessage.getFrom());

    //Check if the message contains data
    if (remoteMessage.getData().size() > 0) {
```

}
//        if (remoteMessage.getNotification() != null) {
//            Log.d(TAG, "Mesage body:" + remoteMessage.getNotification().getBody());
}

Comment: can you elaborate it?